# codeigniter form action tag vs php-html form action tag

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, action

I am a beginner in CodeIgniter framework and I have problem with form action.
I don't have any problems when I do it on this way:

```
<?php
            echo form_open("controller_admin/method1");
?>
<?php
            echo form_close();
?>
```

but when i wrote this:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="<?php site_url('controller_admin/method1') ?>">
</form>
```

Form doesn't want to call controller's method method1, and I don't see why?

Because I'm a beginner I would like to know both ways, but currently only the first one is working.

Comment: try changing site_url to base_url see if it works otherwise  also you have to  to use `<?php echo site_url('controller_admin/method1') ?>`
`<?php echo base_url('controller_admin/method1') ?>`

Comment: And after I changed site_url with base_url unfortunately again nothing happens.
still i don't understand why!

Comment: did you use echo like `<?php echo base_url('controller_admin/method1') ?> `

Comment: Yes that was it! just with site_url.
Thank you very much!

Comment: happy to help :) happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `base_url()`, you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or, manually:load it in function construct of controller

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Once it's loaded, be sure to keep in mind that `base_url()` doesn't implicitly print or echo out anything, rather it returns the value to be printed:

```
echo base_url();
```

**Remember also that the value returned is the site's base url as provided in the config file.**

Comment: no I did all that. I just didn't wrote with echo
Thank you very much! You've helped me a lot!!!